# Pull the entire array (tree) branch using the child ID - PHP Arrauu

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

first of all I am sure this has been asked before in one way or another but I am unsure of how to word it properly so bear with me for a minute.

I have a Category array for my store script with all of my item categories sorted into branches called `$categoryTree`. It sets the category's into relation with their `c.parentcatid` tag. It is build using the following function:

```
public function buildStoreCategoryTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['c.parentcatid'] == $parentId) {
            $children = $this->buildStoreCategoryTree($elements, $element['c.id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

Here is the layout of the database structure, where all of the data is being stored for category information (The whole thing is sent to the above function):

[image]

And finally, here is the information AFTER it has been sorted using the above function into a TREE:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 [c.id] => 1 
        [1] => Radios [c.name] => Radios 
        [2] => radios [c.path] => radios 
        [3] => 0 [c.parentcatid] => 0 
        [children] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [0] => 2 [c.id] => 2 
                [1] => Motorola Radios [c.name] => Motorola Radios 
                [2] => motorola [c.path] => motorola 
                [3] => 1 [c.parentcatid] => 1 
                [children] => Array ( 
                    [0] => Array ( 
                        [0] => 3 [c.id] => 3 
                        [1] => Motorola Handheld Radios [c.name] => Motorola Handheld Radios 
                        [2] => handheld [c.path] => handheld 
                        [3] => 2 [c.parentcatid] => 2 
                    ) 
                    [1] => Array ( 
                        [0] => 4 [c.id] => 4 
                        [1] => Motorola Mobile Radios [c.name] => Motorola Mobile Radios 
                        [2] => mobile [c.path] => mobile 
                        [3] => 2 [c.parentcatid] => 2 
                    )
                ) 
            ) 
            [1] => Array (
                [0] => 5 [c.id] => 5 
                [1] => Icom Radios [c.name] => Icom Radios 
                [2] => icom [c.path] => icom 
                [3] => 1 [c.parentcatid] => 1 
                [children] => Array ( 
                    [0] => Array (
                        [0] => 6 [c.id] => 6 
                        [1] => Icom Handheld Radios [c.name] => Icom Handheld Radios 
                        [2] => handheld [c.path] => handheld 
                        [3] => 5 [c.parentcatid] => 5 
                    ) 
                    [1] => Array ( 
                        [0] => 7 [c.id] => 7 
                        [1] => Icom Mobile Radios [c.name] => Icom Mobile Radios 
                        [2] => mobile [c.path] => mobile 
                        [3] => 5 [c.parentcatid] => 5 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
            [2] => Array (
                [0] => 8 [c.id] => 8 
                [1] => Mics & Speakers [c.name] => Mics & Speakers
                [2] => mics-and-speakers [c.path] => mics-and-speakers 
                [3] => 1 [c.parentcatid] => 1
            ) 
            [3] => Array ( 
                [0] => 9 [c.id] => 9 
                [1] => Mounting Hardware [c.name] => Mounting Hardware 
                [2] => mounts [c.path] => mounts 
                [3] => 1 [c.parentcatid] => 1 
            ) 
            [4] => Array ( 
                [0] => 10 [c.id] => 10 
                [1] => Clips & Assorted [c.name] => Clips & Assorted 
                [2] => other [c.path] => other 
                [3] => 1 [c.parentcatid] => 1 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 11 [c.id] => 11 
        [1] => Miscellaneous [c.name] => Miscellaneous 
        [2] => misc [c.path] => misc 
        [3] => 0 [c.parentcatid] => 0 
        [children] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => 12 [c.id] => 12 
                [1] => LED Lightbars & Products [c.name] => LED Lightbars & Products 
                [2] => led [c.path] => led 
                [3] => 11 [c.parentcatid] => 11 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Now, if I have an item in the `4` category, it is considered to be a **Handheld** radio, a child of **Motorola** and **Radios**. On the item, I store this ID `as catid = '4'`. I now need to find a way to get all of the information from above the branch of 4 back to the first result (radios -> motorola -> handheld -> item here). I would prefer to list them in order, from TOP down, so I can loop through and build an item path `/store/radios/motorola/handheld/item.html` using just the childs id as a starting key.

Is this possible using this layout? Thanks in advance

Comment: Whilst the nested array you've built is great for a menu structure, it's terrible for traversing from a leaf node to the root node. I would suggest maintaining a flat list of all the nodes too, and to iterate over the list, building the path from the leaf node until you reach the root node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the child tree, you need to create an array that maps the record IDs to the records, then you can traverse up from whatever the ID of your target record is.

```
<?php
//Mock category records, would come from the DB in the real world
$categoryRecords = [
    ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'Radios', 'slug'=>'radios', 'parent_id' => 0],
    ['id' => 2, 'title' => 'Accessories', 'slug'=>'misc', 'parent_id' => 1],
    ['id' => 3, 'title' => 'Motorola', 'slug'=>'motorola', 'parent_id' => 1],
    ['id' => 4, 'title' => 'Handheld', 'slug'=>'handheld', 'parent_id' => 3],
    ['id' => 5, 'title' => 'Mobile', 'slug'=>'mobile', 'parent_id' => 3],
    ['id' => 6, 'title' => 'Level 3', 'slug'=>'level-3', 'parent_id' => 5],
    ['id' => 7, 'title' => 'Level 4', 'slug'=>'level-4', 'parent_id' => 6]
];

//Create an array that maps IDs to records
$idMap = [];

foreach($categoryRecords as $currRecord)
{
    $idMap[$currRecord['id']] = $currRecord;
}

/*
 * Now would be a good time to cache this map in something like Redis or Memcache so you don't have to pull
 * the whole category table during every request.
 */

/**
 * Return an array of parent category records for a given category ID
 * @param int $categoryId
 * @return array
 */
function findParentCategories($categoryId)
{
    global $idMap;

    $categories=[];

    while(array_key_exists($categoryId, $idMap))
    {
        $currParentId = $idMap[$categoryId]['parent_id'];
        $categories[] = $idMap[$categoryId];

        $categoryId = $currParentId;
    }

    $categories = array_reverse($categories);

    return $categories;
}

//ID of category requested
$requestedId = 3;

/*
 * Top-to-bottom list of parent categories
 */
$parentCategories = findParentCategories($requestedId);
```